# How can i put a string as a title in header for table calendar?

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, table-calendar

Is it possible to put a const string as a header title for table calendar ?

And the package i am using is

[table calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar)

```
TableCalendar(
        firstDay: DateTime.now(),
        lastDay: DateTime.utc(2040, 10, 10),
        focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
        headerStyle: const HeaderStyle(
          leftChevronVisible: false,
          rightChevronVisible: false,
          formatButtonVisible: false,
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: do you have an image or could you explain in a rough diagram where do you want this title?

Comment: @RisheekMittal, updated the question and added an image. How can i make a calendar like that ?

Comment: So you want to put My Schedules on the top of your calendar? or do you need the code for the whole calendar

Comment: @RisheekMittal I need My Schedules at the top but i also need some actions at the end of that line